# OpenCV for 3D Lucas Kanade?

Tags: opencv, 3d

I want to process 3D images by Lucas Kanade and get the motion field in 3D. Images are of size `[NI, NJ, NK, NT]` where `NI`, `NJ`, `NK` are the number of voxels in `x`, `y`, and `z` directions respectively; and `NT` represents the number of timesteps. Can `OpenCV` do this type of processing? If not, what other tools can be used for this aim?

Comment: You mean like [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html)?

Comment: Yes, is there any way to extend this function for 3D images?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV does not aim on process 3D image data, where the volume is a dense voxel grid (e.g. MRI or CT scans). Thus, OpenCV does not provide a 3D version of its `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` function, or similar.

I was looking for a pre-implemented 3D optical flow aswell. However, I only found this implementation for `MATLAB 7.12`

https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37170-lucas-kanade-optical-flow-method-for-3-d-images

and this iPython notebook:

https://github.com/jabooth/menpo-archive/blob/master/examples/ICCV%202013%203D%20Lucas-Kanade.ipynb

There is a deformable 3D registration in Insight ToolKit (ITK). It generates vector fields that indicate the estimated motion between two frames.

https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/Examples_2RegistrationITKv3_2DeformableRegistration2_8cxx-example.html

**Edit from 2018**: In the meantime, I implemented a 3D Lucas-Kanade by myself. It was primarily used to track things in 3D-OCT volumes. You can find my code here: https://github.com/mlaves/imes4d